# Why is not a==0 in the following code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
    float a=1.0;
    long i;

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        a = a - 0.01;
    }
    printf("%e\n",a);
}
```

Result is: 6.59e-07

Comment: `6.59e-07` is `0.000000659`. This is very close to `0`. Close enough for `float` precision.

Comment: Are you asking why the result is an approximation of zero; or are you asking why you're seeing the result displayed in scientific notation?

Comment: thanks for ur time... my question is why "a" displayed in scientific notation ?

Comment: pmg: Nothing to do with precision of `float`. The problem would happen with arbitrarily-precise floating point types, because `0.01` **does not exist**. OP is actually subtracting something like `0.009999999999999999999796712092658967918623602599836885929107666015625`.

Answer (score 11):

It's a binary floating point number, not a decimal one - therefore you need to expect rounding errors. See the *Basic* section in this article:

> **[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)**

For example, the value 0.01 does not have a precise represenation in binary floating point type. To get a "correct" result in your sample you would have to either round or use a a decimal floating point type (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic#Binary_vs._decimal)):

> Binary fixed-point types are most commonly used, because the rescaling operations can be implemented as fast bit shifts. Binary fixed-point numbers can represent fractional powers of two exactly, but, like binary floating-point numbers, cannot exactly represent fractional powers of ten. If exact fractional powers of ten are desired, then a decimal format should be used. For example, one-tenth (0.1) and one-hundredth (0.01) can be represented only approximately by binary fixed-point or binary floating-point representations, while they can be represented exactly in decimal fixed-point or decimal floating-point representations. These representations may be encoded in many ways, including BCD.

Comment: Also note that 0.01 is not a power of 2, there is a craftly little 5 embedded there, so floating-point number will have junk in it, which builds up into the remaining error you see. Not sure, but 0.125, 8 times may produce a clean loop?

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions here. If you're asking, why is my printf statement displaying the result as `6.59e-07` instead of `0.000000659`, it's because you've used the [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) for Scientific Notation: `%e`. You want `%f` for the floating point `a`.

```
printf("%f\n",a);
```

If you're asking why the result is not exactly zero rather than `0.000000659`, the answer is (as others have pointed out) that with floating point arithmetic using binary numbers you need to expect rounding.

Comment: thanks for your time..... my question was about the result not exactly zero.... thanks for your answer..

Comment: @user692209 In the comments under the question, you've said that your question was about the scientific notation, not the value. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify %f for printing the float number then it will print 0 for variable a.

Comment: Tested. The result is 0.000001

Comment: @Captain: %f will show the precision of 6.Thats why u get the result as 0.000001.

Answer (score 0):

That's floating point numbers rounding errors on the scene. Each time you subtract a fraction you get approximately the result you'd normally expect from a number on paper and so the final result is very close to zero, but not necessarily precise zero.

Answer (score 0):

The precision with floating numbers isn't accurate, that's why you find this result.

Cordially